# Row assignment to numpy array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

```
>>> arr = np.array([[3, -4, 4], [1, -2, 2]])
>>> arr
array([[ 3, -4,  4],
       [ 1, -2,  2]])
>>> arr[1]-(1/3)*arr[0]
array([ 0.        , -0.66666667,  0.66666667])
>>> arr[1] = arr[1]-(1/3)*arr[0]
>>> arr
array([[ 3, -4,  4],
       [ 0,  0,  0]])
```

what do I do wrong? I want to assign the result of the calculation to the second row of the array "arr"

Comment: You can't assign back because its an int array, doesn't support float pt data.

Comment: The array is an `int` array.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you **constructed an array of `int`s**. You can construct an array of `np.float`s by **using the `dtype` parameter**:

```
arr = np.array([[3, -4, 4], [1, -2, 2]],dtype=np.float)
```

Python has a dynamic approach when it comes to types: every element in a list can have a different type. But `numpy` works with matrices where all elements have the same type. Therefore assigning a `float` to an `int` matrix, will convert the row first to `int`s.

This will construct an array:

```
>>> arr = np.array([[3, -4, 4], [1, -2, 2]],dtype=np.float)
>>> arr[1] = arr[1]-(1/3)*arr[0]
>>> arr
array([[ 3.        , -4.        ,  4.        ],
       [ 0.        , -0.66666667,  0.66666667]])
```